# Count occurrences of a factor variable between two posixCT dates

Tags: r, date, count, lubridate

I have a large data frame in which each row represents a single instance of an event. For illustrative purposes, consider a data frame which contains the following five columns:

1. date & time of incident
2. date & time of the incident + 2 hours
3. date & time of the incident - 2 hours
4. city of incident
5. type of incident

Please see below for a reproducible example.

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)
set.seed(5567)

df <- data.frame(time = sample(seq(as.POSIXct('2019/01/10'), 
                                   as.POSIXct('2019/01/20'), 
                                   by="15 mins"), 100))

df <- mutate(df,
             two.Before = df$time - hours(2),
             two.After = df$time + hours(2),
             loc = sample(c("New York", "Boston", "Atlanta", "Chicago"), 100, 
                          replace=TRUE) %>% as.factor,
             type = sample(c("Bus", "Car"), 100, 
                           replace=TRUE) %>% as.factor)

head(df)
```

For each instance, I need to create two new columns:

1. a column which has a count of the number of instances that happened in that *same city* during the two hours before and two hours after the incident.
2. a similar column which has a count of the number of instances that happened in that *same city* that were *bus incidents* and bus incidents only, during the two hours before and two hours after the incident.

If anyone can help with this that would be greatly appreciated. My dates are all posixCt and the categories are all factor. Many thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's generally a sub-optimal idea to use loops in r as any moderate dataset will get really bogged down. Reason for this is specified in other Stack Overflow answers if you are interested. Best practice in r is if you are thinking of using a for loop to go through all records in a data frame, use the [apply family](https://www.datacamp.com/community/tutorials/r-tutorial-apply-family) of functions instead.

I wrote some quick code below which should do the trick fairly quickly and builds on the code you supplied.

```
df$row <- rownames(df)

#Column 1: count occurrences +/- 2hrs within same city
df$col1 <- mapply(function(time, city, row) sum(df[df$row != row,"two.Before"] <= time & df[df$row != row,"two.After"] >= time & df[df$row != row,"loc"] == city), 
              df$time, df$loc, df$row)

#Column2: count occurrences +/- 2hrs within same city and on a bus
df$col2 <- mapply(function(time, city, bus, row) sum(df[df$row != row,"two.Before"] <= time & df[df$row != row,"two.After"] >= time & df[df$row != row,"loc"] == city & df[df$row != row,"type"] == "Bus"), 
              df$time, df$loc, df$type, df$row)

#Remove row index
df <- subset(df, select = -c(row))
```

Let me know if you have any questions. It seems to work as intended for a few data points I tested. This assumes you don't want to count that row in your two counts otherwise all col1 counts would be 1.

### Edit

Code to only review the two hours prior to the incident is below (again builds on the code provided).

```
df$row <- as.numeric(rownames(df))

#Column 1: count occurrences +/- 2hrs within same city
df$col1 <- mapply(function(time, city, row) sum(df[df$row != row,"time"] <= time & df[df$row != row,"two.After"] >= time & df[df$row != row,"loc"] == city), 
              df$time, df$loc, df$row)

#Column2: count occurrences +/- 2hrs within same city and on a bus
df$col2 <- mapply(function(time, city, bus, row) sum(df[df$row != row,"time"] <= time & df[df$row != row,"two.After"] >= time & df[df$row != row,"loc"] == city & df[df$row != row,"type"] == "Bus"), 
              df$time, df$loc, df$type, df$row)
```

Comment: Thank you so much Pete. You are a legend. Helped me tremendously here :)

Comment: No worries, glad to help. As Data Sharkie pointed out, I interpreted your question to mean +/- 2hrs of the date and time in the df$time column. If that's incorrect, let me know and I'll update the code to reflect this.

Comment: HI Pete. One last question on this. I suddenly realized that if we are trying to predict some future event, we won't have information about the number of occurrences in the two hours after it happened! I tried but failed at amending your code to only do counts for the two hours before the incident. Any chance you could help me out :)?

Comment: Hi DJC, I've edited my answer to only include the two hours prior to an incident but otherwise kept the rules the same.

Answer (score 0):

My way of doing it is with loops. Runtime is quite high but it works accurately.
First is `col1` which counts for occurrences within +-2 hours in the same city. 
Note: the last line in the loop does `-1` this is to eliminate double counting of first observation.
Second is `col2` which does all the same as above but also includes type = "Bus". 
Note: the last line in the loop does `-1` this to eliminate double counting of first observation (a little different from the 1st loop because we need to make sure there is more than 1 observation in the first place, because not all types are "Bus").

```
df$col1<-0
for (i in 1:nrow(df)){
  for (j in 1:nrow(df)){
    if (hour(df[i,]$time)==hour(df[j,]$time) & df[i,]$loc==df[j,]$loc) 
      {df[i,]$col1<-df[i,]$col1+1}
    else if ((hour(df[i,]$time)-hour(df[j,]$time))<2 & (hour(df[i,]$time)-hour(df[j,]$time))>(-2) & df[i,]$loc==df[j,]$loc)
      {df[i,]$col1<-df[i,]$col1+1}
  }
  df[i,]$col1<-df[i,]$col1-1
}


df$col2<-0
for (i in 1:nrow(df)){
  for (j in 1:nrow(df)){
    if (hour(df[i,]$time)==hour(df[j,]$time) & df[i,]$loc==df[j,]$loc & df[j,]$type=="Bus")
      {df[i,]$col2<-df[i,]$col2+1}
    else if ((hour(df[i,]$time)-hour(df[j,]$time))<2 & (hour(df[i,]$time)-hour(df[j,]$time))>(-2) & 
             df[i,]$loc==df[j,]$loc & df[j,]$type=="Bus")
      {df[i,]$col2<-df[i,]$col2+1}
  }
  if (df[i,]$col2>0){df[i,]$col2<-df[i,]$col2-1}
}
```

You can type `head(df)` to take a look at the results or just view the entire dataset.

Please let me know if you have any questions about any part of the code.

Comment: Hey Data Sharkie, thanks for the help. For some reason your code isn't running for me. I receive this message when I try to run it: "Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, "col2", value = numeric(0)) : replacement has 0 rows, data has 1"

Comment: Hey @DJC! So you have to run your code, then add mine at the bottom. I just tested the full code on my computer and it worked.

Comment: Kept on trying but no dice :(

Comment: @DJC The solution above by Pete M doesn't do the count accurately because it takes into account the actual date. You need to trim the data to just look at the hours like 10pm, 11pm and so on (not 2017-09-10 10pm; 2017-09-17 11pm) if you want to focus on just hours of observations and not dates.

Comment: @DJC I found an error in the code you mentioned, I made a typo in one of the lines. The code is now updated. Please try to run it and let me know.

Comment: thanks for following up. I'm confused - I think it is correct, at least based on my spot checks. 
for example, let us change the seed to 557. row 37 is now: chicago, (2019-01-11 10:30:00) and the count from col 1 = is 2. If we sort by date, we do indeed see two other observations in Chicago in the two hours before. one at 2019-01-11 08:45:00, and the other at 2019-01-11 10:00:00.

Comment: @DJC I mean I ran the code and the results seem to be different from mine. My point is I only looked at time like 10pm, 11pm and so on, regardless of the date. If it's 2019-01-01 10pm and 2019-01-02 10pm, it will count them, because I only work with time data rather than time and date. I am not sure which one exactly you were looking for.

Comment: i was actually looking for time & date, not just time. really appreciate the help tho :)